# Android GCM - Class not found exception

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use GCM with appengine, as shown in google's tutorial.
On the server side, when I'm trying to do:

```
    Sender sender = new Sender(API_KEY);
com.google.android.gcm.server.Message message = new com.google.android.gcm.server.Message.Builder().addData("message",m).build();
for (String regId : u.getDeviceIds()) {
    try {
        Result result = sender.send(message,regId, 3);
        System.out.println("Message to " + u.getName() + " : " + result);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

I'm getting:

```
    org.restlet.resource.UniformResource doCatch: Exception or error caught in resource
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException
    at il.ac.technion.ssdl.hitch.model.GCMServices.sendMessage(GCMServices.java:24)
```

Line 24 at GCMServices.java is `Sender sender = new Sender(API_KEY);`

Regarding classpath, I have:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/gcm-server.jar"/>
```

Which is the correct path.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its a common problem , download this, add to classpath:
[SimpleJson](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/detail?name=json-simple-1.1.1.jar)